# How to elegantly set precision/tolerance when using numpy to take very small values to actual 0?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make numpy to take small values to 0 without doing it by myself explicitly for every result.

Is there a clean way to do it without calling to cool functions as `numpy.isclose` or setting it to zero: `c[c<1e-20]=0` or any other similar approach. What is the cleanest why to do it for the whole session (as clean as the matlab behavior at the bottom of the post)?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randn(3,3)
b=np.random.randn(3,3)
a[1,:]=1e-20
c=np.matmul(a,b)
c[c<1e-20]=0
```

Which gives:

```
>> c
array([[  4.16639233e-01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.23275238e+00],
       [  1.59739149e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   7.97659305e-01,   1.14217399e-01]])
```

Compare to matlab:

```
>> format long
>> a=randn(3,3);
>> b=randn(3,3);
>> a(1,:)=1e-20;
>> a*b

ans =

   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
  -0.123562969836108  -0.148234256997880   4.136510695446545
   0.596809154812933   1.837267263414820  -2.998336234205494
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`. For documentation refer [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
a=np.random.randn(3,3)
b=np.random.randn(3,3)
a[1,:]=1e-20
c=np.matmul(a,b)

print(c)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.31346501,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.81057613,  1.916861  ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: It seems a little different. `set_printoptions` only effect how it is printed but not the original values. But in matlab, it seems it loses precision. However, I'm not familiar with matlab, not sure about it.